# How to undo the quantization step in DCT?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, dct, jpeg

How can I do point by point multiplication of the quantized DCT coefficients with the quantization matrix before computing the inverse DCT for each block? I want to modify the reconstruction algorithm to approximately undo the quantization step shown here:

```
for i = 1:Blocks
    for j=1:Blocks
        irange = (i-1)*8+1:(i-1)*8+8;
        jrange = (j-1)*8+1:(j-1)*8+8;
        quantblock = round(y(irange,jrange)./Q);
        quant_DCTblocks(irange,jrange) = quantblock;
    end
end
figure
imagesc(quant_DCTblocks)
colormap(gray)
set(gca,'Xtick',[])
set(gca,'Ytick',[])
axis('square')
title('quantized DCT Coeffs')
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code it looks like the *quantization* step is doing two things:

1. dividing by `Q`, and
2. rounding.

Undoing the divide by `Q` is easy. The rounding is where the actual quantizing is happening though, and unfortunately that is the part that you cannot undo- at least not without more information. Rounding causes information to be lost and you cannot undo that.

Comment: So can you explicitly tell me which lines of the code should be changed? except rounding ?

Comment: If you don't want to quantize just don't round.